# How long should one let the motor turn (witout driving) to re-charge the car battery, after having using it to charge a laptop's battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, automotive, generator, alternator

I'm going to spend 1 week with no electricity. I won't need any for everyday life (I do this each year), except to **charge my laptop's battery** (10.8V, 5.2Ah, 57 Wh) three or four times.

I have a [car 12V->220V converter on cigar lighter plug](https://www.cdiscount.com/pdt2/0/0/1/1/700x700/auc3513764330001/rw/convertisseur-wp-12-220v-150w-avec-prise-usb.jpg) (I'll use the laptop charger 220V->20V on it - I know it would much more efficient to have a car 12V->20V laptop charger, I'll consider this for next time). If we assume 50% efficiency, one full recharge of the laptop's battery will drain ~120 Wh from the car battery.

If it's a 60Ah 12V car battery, this means it will make it drop from 720 Wh to 600 Wh. Is that correct?

**Question**: After having charged the laptop during 1 or 2 hours with the car cigar lighter plug (fortunately the cigar lighter plug does not switch off after a few minutes), **how long should I let the motor of the car turn**, without driving but alternator working, to compensate this drop of 120 Wh, so that the car battery is 100% charged again? So that two days later, I can do it again.

(Note: using a power generator is not an option for out of topic reasons)

Comment: I don't think you can develop a good estimate. You have already provided a rough guess for laptop charging efficiency. You also need to guess at car battery charging efficiency at idle. I would try to determine when the car charging current drops or cuts off.

Comment: Take your stick shift car, and park at the top of a hill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of estimate, let's assume the following:

- Battery charge current = 0.1C = 0.1*60A = **6A max**
- Starter current is 200A x 3 seconds

When you start the car, you consume:

- 200A * 3s / 3600s = **0.17 Ah per start**

Your estimated laptop charge is 120 Wh, or conservatively about **10 Ah** per complete charge from the car battery.

So the total consumption to charge the battery, then start the car is:

- 10 Ah + 0.17 Ah = **10.17 Ah**.

Charging rate is the 0.1C rate of 6A, so:

- 10.17Ah / 6A = 1.695h or **102 minutes.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is a charge rate of 6A common for a car alternator when the car is idle? (I have no idea about this).

Comment: PS @hacktastical: can I check with a multimeter if the battery is fully charged again? What are the nominal voltage values for a 100% or 80% charged 12V 60Ah car battery?